# Gstreamer videoconvert GPU over

Tags: video-streaming, gpu, gstreamer

Videoconvert dont use gpu. How can I do videoconvert using GPU? When I delete convert video. Although the stream is 3840x2160. It comes to 3240x3840 and turns to grayscale. Stream Video: [Media Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rt9m.png)

Stream Sender: gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=4k30fps.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.10.186 port 9001

Stream Client Code:

```
string gst_pipe1 = "udpsrc port=9001 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";

VideoCapture cap1(gst_pipe1, CAP_GSTREAMER);

if (!cap1.isOpened())
{
    cout << "VideoCapture not opened" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

Mat frame1;
cuda::GpuMat frameGPU1;

while (true) {

    cap1.read(frame1);
    frameGPU1.upload(frame1);
    imshow("1", frameGPU1);

    if (waitKey(1) == 'r')
        break;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. Opencv accepts gray scale or BGRA tyes only, can you try changing element parameter of videoconvert to sink BGRA format of video.

Comment: @Mayank I don't think it has anything to do with the format. because I've done different experiments before. i think i should change appsink. I saw nveglglessink. It gives output on the GPU. But I guess I'm compiling on cards like Jetson TX. Couldn't find it for Ubuntu.